# Does the ESP32 WROOM-32 have an internal RTC?

Tags: timer, esp32, rtc, sleep

I am working on an ESP32 WROOM-32 now. My purpose is to have it read some data every 15 minutes, in between the ESP32 goes to sleep mode.

Does the ESP32 have an internal RTC or timer? I searched on google but I didn't get a clear explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ESP32 does not have a real time clock - you cannot tell it to wake up at a particular time.  It does have a timer that can wake it from deep sleep after a given time.

You can use the deep sleep wake up timer like this:

```c
esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup((uint64_t)sleepTimeSeconds * 1000000);
esp_deep_sleep_start();
```

You set the sleep timer with [esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup.](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/sleep_modes.html)  The time period is in microseconds.  With the timer set, the ESP32 will automatically wake up after the set time period.

The timer is not terribly accurate.  In one project where I've used it, the wakeup varies by as much as a couple of minutes over an hour.  That is, it should sleep for 60 minutes, but it may actually wake up after anywhere from 59 minutes to more than 60 minutes.

If the 15 minute interval needs to be more accurately timed than that then you will need to use an accurate real time clock module.
Alternatively, you could have the ESP32 wake up from deep sleep every minute or so and check the time via NTP over WiFi. The final sleep would be calculated from the NTP time.  Over a minute or so, you should be able to get better than one second accuracy.  The NTP reference would keep your samples from "wandering" due to the inaccurate timer.

---

The [datasheet of the ESP32](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_datasheet_en.pdf) mentions an RTC module, but that seems to be a far different thing than the usual expectation of a real time clock (RTC.)  A real time clock usually refers to a module with a clock and calendar function that keeps track of the current date and time and that often provides "alarms" that can wake the main processor at a specific date and time.

The ESP32 RTC module only has a timer that runs even in hibernation mode as well as some RAM that it can retain in deep sleep mode.  There are some interrupt inputs that can be used to have the RTC wake up the main processor.

There's no "wall clock" or "calendar" in the ESP32 RTC module.

Comment: Thank you @JRE !